# Can't trigger change on option with CasperJS

Tags: jquery, html-select, casperjs

I have this html:

```
<select class="ik-target" name="make_id" id="the_maker_id" data-ik-class="maker-select">
 <option value="" class="empty-item">Choose maker</option>
 <optgroup label="Some of them">
  ...
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Chosen">
    <option value="2" style="text-indent: 10px;">A</option>
    <option value="5" style="text-indent: 10px;">B</option>
    <option value="16" style="text-indent: 10px;">C</option>
    <option value="819" style="text-indent: 10px;">D</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

I then try this (which usually works):

```
var thisnow = "5";
this.evaluate(function(valueOptionSelect){
   $('select#form_maker_id optgroup[label="Chosen"] option').val(valueOptionSelect);
   $('select#form_maker_id optgroup[label="Chosen"] option').trigger("change");
},thisnow);
```

But that does not change the option value from default `value=""`

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: Firstly, you should trigger `change` on `select`, not `option`(s). And secondly, the same for `.val()`

Comment: @A.Wolff like this? `$('select#form_maker_id optgroup[label="Chosen"]')`? Not working :/

Comment: No, i meant e.g: `$('#form_maker_id').val(valueOptionSelect);` and `$('#form_maker_id').trigger('change');` and btw this could be chained: `$('#form_maker_id').val(valueOptionSelect).change();`

Comment: @A.Wolff Not working as well :/

Comment: @A.Wolff that select is in a form, maybe something about it? There is no `method='get'` on that form

Comment: @A.Wolff It works, my fault. Great! Post as answer please, I accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set value of `select` element and trigger `change` event on it too:

```
$('#form_maker_id').val(valueOptionSelect).change();
```